# MFC dock at bottom right

Tags: c++, mfc, dock

I have a pane in an C++ MFC app that I want to dock bottom right as shown in orange in this image. Currently it is going right across the bottom (red). 
see http://screencast.com/t/kSpPhvZkgBGj

This is how the user can do it in VS2008. 
http://screencast.com/t/kSpPhvZkgBGj

What position is this called? How can I get the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order the panes are created. I developed a software that even has two interface versions, with completely different layouts.

Outlook Layout:
[image: Outlook Layout]

Ribbon Layout
[image]

As you can see in the Outlook layout the 3 panes at top got at the left in the Ribbon layout; and the information bar moved from the top to the bottom.

This got some annoying work to be done. I used CDockablePane entities. Are you using them?